# Maven build fails as I add one more dependency to pom.xml

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, m2eclipse, maven-assembly-plugin

I'm trying to build project with Maven in Eclipse. Here is my `pom.xml`:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<groupId>com.osnewhorizon</groupId>
<artifactId>Convert</artifactId>
<version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>jar</packaging>

<name>Convert</name>
<url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>junit</groupId>
        <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
        <version>4.11</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-assembly-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3</version>
            <configuration>
                <descriptorRefs>
                    <descriptorRef>jar-with-dependencies</descriptorRef>
                </descriptorRefs>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>com.osnewhorizon.Convert.App</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>single</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
        <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.2</version>
            <configuration>
                <source>1.8</source>
                <target>1.8</target>

            </configuration>
        </plugin>

    </plugins>
</build>
```

This works very well and builds jar-with-dependencies as expected. But as I add one more dependency to the `<dependencies>` section it fails to build. The dependency that I add is:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.groupdocs</groupId>
  <artifactId>groupdocs-conversion</artifactId>
  <version>1.3.0</version>
  <type>jar</type></dependency>
```

The library is installed to mvn, as I add it to dependencies, I can use it classes, but when trying to run `mvn clean verify` I've got BUILD FAILED with following log (*Updated log with -X argument*):

```
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time: 31.836 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2016-04-12T11:38:00+02:00
[INFO] Final Memory: 34M/847M
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (default) on project Convert: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single failed. IllegalArgumentException -> [Help 1]
org.apache.maven.lifecycle.LifecycleExecutionException: Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single (default) on project Convert: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single failed.
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:224)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:153)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:145)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:108)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleModuleBuilder.buildProject(LifecycleModuleBuilder.java:76)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.builder.singlethreaded.SingleThreadedBuilder.build(SingleThreadedBuilder.java:51)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.LifecycleStarter.execute(LifecycleStarter.java:116)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.doExecute(DefaultMaven.java:361)
    at org.apache.maven.DefaultMaven.execute(DefaultMaven.java:155)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.execute(MavenCli.java:584)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.doMain(MavenCli.java:213)
    at org.apache.maven.cli.MavenCli.main(MavenCli.java:157)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:483)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launchEnhanced(Launcher.java:289)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.launch(Launcher.java:229)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.mainWithExitCode(Launcher.java:415)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.classworlds.launcher.Launcher.main(Launcher.java:356)
Caused by: org.apache.maven.plugin.PluginExecutionException: Execution default of goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-assembly-plugin:2.3:single failed.
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:144)
    at org.apache.maven.lifecycle.internal.MojoExecutor.execute(MojoExecutor.java:208)
    ... 19 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException
    at sun.net.www.ParseUtil.decode(ParseUtil.java:202)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.parseSpecs(JarURLConnection.java:181)
    at java.net.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:158)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.JarURLConnection.<init>(JarURLConnection.java:81)
    at sun.net.www.protocol.jar.Handler.openConnection(Handler.java:41)
    at java.net.URL.openConnection(URL.java:972)
    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:1038)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.components.io.resources.PlexusIoURLResource.getContents(PlexusIoURLResource.java:34)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.ArchiveEntry.getInputStream(ArchiveEntry.java:106)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.zipFile(AbstractZipArchiver.java:552)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.addResources(AbstractZipArchiver.java:387)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.createArchiveMain(AbstractZipArchiver.java:312)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.zip.AbstractZipArchiver.execute(AbstractZipArchiver.java:211)
    at org.codehaus.plexus.archiver.AbstractArchiver.createArchive(AbstractArchiver.java:897)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.archiver.AssemblyProxyArchiver.createArchive(AssemblyProxyArchiver.java:512)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.archive.DefaultAssemblyArchiver.createArchive(DefaultAssemblyArchiver.java:185)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.assembly.mojos.AbstractAssemblyMojo.execute(AbstractAssemblyMojo.java:452)
    at org.apache.maven.plugin.DefaultBuildPluginManager.executeMojo(DefaultBuildPluginManager.java:133)
    ... 20 more
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] 
[ERROR] For more information about the errors and possible solutions, please read the following articles:
[ERROR] [Help 1] http://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/MAVEN/PluginExecutionException
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Can you run `mvn clean verify -e -X` and provide more details about the error? At first, it seems an issue on the assembly plugin while decoding the content of the jar to build the fat jar, but a bit more of stacktrace chain could help

Comment: Use an uptodate version of maven-assembly-plugin see http://maven.apache.org/plugins/

Comment: What worked for me was an updated version of mysql-connector-java. Error happened with 8.0.12, but not with 8.0.13